# Program to repair grub?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, kernel

I have had windows eight and Ubuntu 13.04 dual booting and working fine(using EasyBCD) I had created partition for Ubuntu of exactly 20GB. Some time later, after never using Ubuntu, I went into Window's partition tool and deleted my Ubuntu partition. It said it erased everything on it. I then added this 20GB onto my hardrive/windows8 partition. I also deleted easy BCD. Everything was going fine. I turned the computer off that night and this morning it said

```
 'windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause'
   File:\NSTAutoNeoGrub1.mbr
   status: 0xc000000fI
```

I re-installed Ubuntu from a USB and all my data and Windows system files are there, but I am stuck running ubuntu. I believe all I need to do is find the 'windows8.exe' file and boot from that. Can someone please help here?

My error report for boot-repair is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6426199/
Also I tried updating grub using:

```
- sudo update-grub, but:Generating grub.cfg ... Found linux image:   
   /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-13-generic Found initrd image:   
   /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-13-generic Found linux image:   
   /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic Found initrd image:   
   /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic Found memtest86+ image:   
   /boot/memtest86+.bin Found Windows 8 (loader) on /dev/sda1 Found   
   Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda2 Adding Aptosid   
   2010-02-keres-kde-lite-amd64-201009132215 on /dev/sda5 proc sysfs   
   none none none none udev devpts tmpfs none none none none systemd   
   gvfsd-fuse gvfsd-fuse /dev/sda2 Aptosid   
   2010-02-keres-kde-lite-amd64-201009132215 on /dev/sda5 proc sysfs   
   none none none none udev devpts tmpfs none none none none systemd   
   gvfsd-fuse gvfsd-fuse /dev/sda2 Aptosid   
   2010-02-keres-kde-lite-amd64-201009132215 on /dev/sda5 proc sysfs   
   none none none none udev devpts tmpfs none none none none systemd   
   gvfsd-fuse gvfsd-fuse /dev/sda2 Aptosid   
   2010-02-keres-kde-lite-amd64-201009132215 on /dev/sda5 proc sysfs   
   none none none none udev devpts tmpfs none none none none systemd   
   gvfsd-fuse gvfsd-fuse /dev/sda2 error: syntax error. error: Incorrect
   command. error: syntax error. Syntax error at line 296 Syntax errors 
   are detected in generated GRUB config file. Ensure that there are no 
   errors in /etc/default/grub and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a 
   bug report with /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file attached.done
```

My grub file is:

```
 If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
 /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
 For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
 Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
 This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
 the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"
 Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
 The resolution used on graphical terminal
 note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
 you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
 Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true
 Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
 Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
   GRUB_GFXMODE=1366x768
```

Comment: did you able to use windows?

Comment: No, It says: 'windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause'
   File:\NSTAutoNeoGrub1.mbr
   status: 0xc000000fI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot windows installation disc,and click on the option `Repair your computer` on startup.And then select `command prompt` option.Run the below commands on that,

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

Comment: My laptop didn't come with an instillation disk, sorry, do you have any other ideas...

Comment: create a bootable windows usb,boot from that.

Comment: Look, I am usually pretty good with computers, and know what I'm doing, but I do not know to to create a bootable windows USB without starting windows, can you please explain this?

Comment: did you able to boot into ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, I can boot into Ubuntu

Comment: using `WinUSB` software create a bootable widows usb from ubuntu.

Comment: I have downloaded WinUSB, but it is a .exe file, I have tried running it through Wine and RunOnLinux, but I can't open it?

Comment: Try this command on terminal 'sudo apt-get install winusb'

Comment: E: Unable to locate package winusb

Comment: run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight`then `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install winusb` commands on terminal.

Comment: Dude, really sorry, but I get the exact same problem even when do those extra commands, I was going to post the entire command thing, but it was 22,7000 Characters too long... ;) BTW I really appreciate your help

Comment: Err http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
I got this error does it mean anything?

Comment: Woah, I tried again doing the entire process and got this:matt@matt-Satellite-Pro-C850:~$ apt-get install winusb
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install winusb`

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package winusb
matt@matt-Satellite-Pro-C850:~$

Comment: I still get this: Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done E: Unable to locate package winusb matt@matt-Satellite-Pro-C850:~$ –

Comment: dowload winusb from here http://congelli.eu/download/winusb/winusb-1.0.11.tar.gz

Comment: Ok, I am really new to linux, I have downloaded the file you gave me, I have typed: sudo apt-get install winusb, but it unable to locate, is there a specific folder I need to put it in? I extracted it and popped it on my desktop...

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file see this page to install downloaded `tar.gz` file

Comment: Could you please download the file, and install it. Then tell me exactly what you did? Sorry, I am having so much trouble with this...

Comment: see this page to install winusb http://askubuntu.com/questions/381953/how-to-install-winusb-in-ubuntu-13-10

Comment: Quick question, I type: sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/colingille-freshlight-saucy.list It opens But I can't then type sudo apt-get update

Comment: instead of `nano` type `gedit` on that command,it will open that file and change the name saucy to raring and save the file.Then run `sudo apt-get update` and then run `sudo apt-get install `winusb`.

Comment: matt@matt-Satellite-Pro-C850:~$ sudo apt-get install winusb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
N: Ignoring file 'colingille-freshlight-saucy.list.save.2' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'colingille-freshlight-raring.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

Comment: N: Ignoring file 'colingille-freshlight-saucy.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'colingille-freshlight-raring.list.save.2' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unable to locate package winusb
matt@matt-Satellite-Pro-C850:~$

Comment: Ok, Avinash Raj, thank you for consistently helping me, however I redownloaded win8 and did a fresh install using another computer, a USB and a lot  of work. Thanks again for trying to help, but I have solved the problem.