# How to install Winusb?

Tags: software-installation

I want to install winusb software on ubuntu 13.10. Installation via PPA method doesn't work.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install winusb
```

Comment: The `ppa:colingille/freshlight` ppa is available only for versions upto `13.04`. https://launchpad.net/~colingille/+archive/freshlight

Comment: yes,i know.I already mention that.

Comment: No. :) You hadn't mentioned the ppa, I guessed it. Please add the relevant ppa to the question.

Comment: I have reported the problem to the PPA owner. Hope that somebody helps you with a workaround.

Comment: Per [the owner of the PPA's comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/381953/how-to-install-winusb-in-ubuntu-13-10#comment495963_381983) this question is now obsolete

Comment: **Why close?** its the only question we have on how to install Winusb, and its answered. We may consider to remove the ppa bits again to let the answer be an answer.

Comment: @Takkat Because this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/381953/how-to-install-winusb-in-ubuntu-13-10#comment495963_381983

Comment: The question appears to be valid again (at least for Trusty) - see http://askubuntu.com/questions/489546/installing-winusb-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I believe this question is a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu

Comment: I found a working Installation of WinUSB here http://justcode.me/ubuntu/how-to-create-windows-bootable-usb-in-ubuntu-winusb/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To install do this.  just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install winusb
```

It has been tested, and it works OK.  See image below

[image]
Before 13.10 was added to the PPA, a work around is to do the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/colingille-freshlight-saucy.list
(change saucy to raring)
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install winusb
```

Comment: I have just uploaded a version for Ubuntu 13.10 on my PPA, so it is now possible to install winusb directly. Thanks Mitch for your answer.

Comment: For the ones of you who get a `512 error` read [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/539803/269282) to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu 14.04, the repository is not current, but you can download the .deb and install with dpkg

Download the [64-bit `.deb` here](https://launchpad.net/~colingille/+archive/ubuntu/freshlight/+files/winusb_1.0.11%2Bsaucy1_amd64.deb),

or the [32-bit here](https://launchpad.net/~colingille/+archive/ubuntu/freshlight/+files/winusb_1.0.11%2Bsaucy1_i386.deb),

and then go to [this answer on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489546/installing-winusb-on-ubuntu-14-04) for complete installation instructions.

Answer (score 2):

WinUSB doesn't support current versions of Ubuntu, however WoeUSB which is an updated fork of the WinUSB application can be installed from Ubuntu Software or from the terminal with the following commands:

```
sudo snap install --edge woe-usb  
sudo snap connect woe-usb:removable-media
```

To launch the woe-usb snap package command line tool run the following command:

```
woe-usb.woeusb
```

Connect the woe-usb:removable-media plug to the woe-usb:removable-media slot in order to enable USB devices to be mounted automatically by WoeUSB.

1. Search for woeusb in Ubuntu Software and click it to go to the woe-usb screen.
2. Click the Permissions button.
3. Toggle the *Read/Write files on removeable storage devices* slider from OFF to ON as shown in the below screenshot.
4. Authenticate with your user password when the *Authentication Required* window pops up.

[image: woe-usb Permissions]