# how to make bootable usb file of win7.nrg in ubuntu?

Tags: installation, 13.04, boot, usb

i have image of windows 7 ultimate in my laptop and i burned it into dvd but now it's currupted and i can't use the media. and i want to learn how to make usb bootable disk of win7.nrg into my pen drive. i tried diskpart but it was useless. so please suggest me or help me how can i make it in ubuntu... i'll be thankfull.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is convert the .nrg file to ISO.  To do that you need to install nrg2iso.

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install nrg2iso
```

Once installed type the command below to do the conversion:

```
nrg2iso win7.nrg win7.iso
```

Once that is done, then look the [How to install WinUSB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/381953/how-to-install-winusb-in-ubuntu-13-10/381983#381983), to create the bootable USB under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Use universal USB software and start in and chose your pen drive and chose win 7 iso file and click in start batton and simply your pen drive is bootable