# Installing WinUSB on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I am unable to install WinUSB in Ubuntu 14.04 using command:

`sudo apt-get install winusb`

What is the correct way to install WinUSB in Ubuntu 14.04? Or is there any other application available to create Windows bootable USB in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Hello .. My question is not.. How to make bootable for windows on Ubuntu.. My question is how to install winusb on Ubuntu 14.04 because at the I posted this question there is no way to get winusb on Ubuntu 14.04 .. Then why this people marked it as duplicate .. What heck