# Missing Operating System - Windows7 - Boot from USB

Tags: boot, usb

I am using an HP TouchSmart 600 that came from factory with Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit. I have decided to get rid of it and installed Ubuntu 14.04 booting from USB and everything went perfect. Now, I want to install again Windows 7 so I downloaded the ISO image from the web and created a bootable USB using YUMI from [pendrivelinux.com](http://www.pendrivelinux.com) (my CD/DVD does not work and I don't have original windows CD) after reboot I keep getting this message "Missing Operating System", then Ubuntu is loaded normally.

I have been working to solving this for several days already and tried everything in the forums but nothing worked for me:

1. I have downloaded many different ISO versions from the web to make sure the files were not corrupted.
2. I have formatted the USB with `gparted` in NTFS and also in FAT32 before installing the ISO and I have also tried to boot in all possible usb slots to make sure I am using the primary one.
3. I have updated the BIOS to boot from the USB device as a very first option.

PS: Please note I am not using any partition, I just want to install Windows 7 back in my machine and after that I will probably use dual-boot to keep using Ubuntu. I wanted to add how the USB looks like but when I run the tree command from terminal is a very long file so just for your reference this is what I can see in the root: I have 6 folders (boot, efi, sources, support, upgrade, yumi) and 4 files (autorun.inf, bootmgr, bootmgr.efi, setup.exe)

Please do let me know if you need any extra information from my side.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with **`mkusb`** version 12. Install mkusb according to this link,

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb

If you run standard Ubuntu, you need an extra instruction to get the repository Universe. (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu have the repository Universe activated automatically.)

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe  # only for standard Ubuntu

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
```

See the detailed information at this link, describing how to create a drive to install Windows,

[mkusb - Windows USB install drive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive)

Answer (score 0):

Try using WINUSB,very easy to use, i just used it to boot windows 7 ultimate x64 and it worked perfectly, since there is no package on the repos of Ubuntu 14.04 i give you this link with a tutorial of how install it that also contains the download links.

[Installing WinUSB on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489546/installing-winusb-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Add some description man! You should mention some important points about it when external links are suggested.

Comment: I have followed that wonderful tutorial and i realized i did 2 things wrong: 

1)I did not place a boot flag in gparted.
2)I was using the most updated version of UNetbootin so i was not able to select the correct usb. I am re-sending the link (as the initial answer was edited) in case it can help somebody else:

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/create-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive.html

Thanks a lot z3ro, you really helped me out with this. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated the GRUB after Windows 7 installation? Grub menu can be updated or repaired or modified for dual-boot. See this page [Grub update](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2).