# winusb installing windows

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-7

m novice to ubuntu, and pretty novice to termianl and commands I 
followed commands on this page "**[Installing WinUSB on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489546/installing-winusb-on-ubuntu-14-04)**" to install winusb.

lastly it asked where to install or upgrade grub on last step with list of all hardrive on my system. I panicked and cancelled and closed terminal will this affect my default grub of ubuntu or can i do something to revert back this stupidness.

**please do not mark as offtopic** this question. please help me in this new Neighbourhood of Ubuntu 14.04.

thanks guys..
I'm not shutting down my system untill it is guaranteed my grub is safe and wont cause any problem next time i run Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Don't panic! you were installing an application which it might was trying to update your grub and you just canceled it, that's it!

by using this:

```
sudo dd bs=512 count=1 if=/dev/sda 2>/dev/null | strings
```

you can see the first 512 bytes of the device, result would be something like this:

```
ZRr=
`|f 
\|f1
GRUB
Geom
Hard Disk
Read
 Error
```

you can see the Grube is there

p.s: you may need to change the value of "sda" based on your hard drive partitions.