# Replacing Ubuntu with Windows 8

Tags: 15.04, windows-8

I need to reinstall Windows 8 on my machine where I've installed ubuntu 15.04. I have no DVD drive and need to run it from a USB stick. Windows supports this but I cannot run the .exe windows file that creates the usb stick for rebooting from the USB. Hope someone have an idea on how to solve this.

Comment: the site from where i can create the usb stick  www.windows.microsoft.com/da-dk/windows-8/upgrade-product-key-only

Comment: What Windows 8 iso do you need ?

Comment: Hi Neil, not sure if i've understood your question right, but im trying to reinstall win8 from a usb stick and trying to create the stick using the program (Windows8-setup.exe) provided by MS from their webpage also shown above

Comment: Windows 8 pro/home/starter/ is it OEM ?

Comment: If you can't download the EXE file to download the ISO, download the ISO straight instead. Windows 8 cracked ISO torrents aren't illegal as long as you still purchase the key and not the cracked one. `WinUSB` is Ubuntu-supported so grab them on Google too.

Comment: The window8 came preinstalled on my machine, so i think it must be a win8 home edition

Comment: For Win 8, you will have to torrent but you can get Win 10.iso here https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10ISO free, use the Win 8 licence key you have for your PC, to create a USB with an easy to use GUI follow http://askubuntu.com/questions/489546/installing-winusb-on-ubuntu-14-04 I don't know why no one has suggested this yet ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dd if=/path/to/iso of=/dev/sdX bs=16M`
Sorry to see you go.

Comment: Hi Wilhelm, Thank you for your reply. I'll be back and run it as dual boot. The problem is i'm complete novice to ubuntu and do not completely understand your help

Comment: Cool :) It's a pleasure.

Comment: Do you have the .iso file for windows?

Comment: no, i need to run a downloaded file that will create the usb stick so i can boot from the win8 startup usb stick. Its a windows8-setup.exe file and i cannot run that on my ubuntu

Comment: Have you tried WINE?

Comment: yes, that did not work

Answer (score 0):

You could download a trial version of windows .iso and run it in a VM (Virtual Machine like Virtual Box). Then do what you need to do in the VM, if your PC will support a VM.

Windows 7 .iso download link: [HERE](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows7)

Windows 10 .iso download link: [HERE](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10ISO)

Virtual Box (VM): [HERE](https://www.virtualbox.org/)

Instruction how to install Win 7 in a VM: [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1DhwS4eZExU)