# How do I install WinUSB on 14.10

Tags: apt

I need to install WinUSB but no matter what I try it doesn't work, I always get an error no matter what I do.

This doesn't work

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install winusb
```

Comment: which error ? show us the output. http://askubuntu.com/questions/381953/how-to-install-winusb

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Y0TFkMEt

Comment: the ppa repository has not been updated since saucy. so the last supported distro is saucy.

Comment: How do I downgrade then?

Comment: **Nominating this answer to reopen as it is more up-to-date as its so-called "duplicate"...** (or incorporation?)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following commands based on [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu)

Since you are running the Ubuntu 14.10 (Utopic) You need to replace trusty with utopic in the commands listed. The commands should look like this.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight
sudo sh -c "sed -i 's/utopic/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/colingille-freshlight-utopic.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install winusb
```

You can start with the second line as you have already added the repository.  The PPA is not updated beyond Saucy. Without the second line `sudo apt-get update` fails as there is no version specific to Trusty or Utopic. This code tells update to use the Saucy version of winusb from the PPA in the Ubuntu 14.10 (also known as Utopic) .

Hope this helps

Comment: the second line of code -- in which you have used sed-- is necessary ? if for what ? we already added PPA first right ?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds the PPA is not updated beyond Saucy. `apt-get update` fails as there is no version specific to Trusty or Utopic. This code tells update to use the Saucy version from the PPA instead.