# Can't make a Windows 7 Bootable USB

Tags: usb, windows, startup-disk

I'm trying to use Startup Disk Creator to burn a Windows 7 iso file to a USB, but it doesn't appear to do anything when I try to select a file.

[Here's a video of what I'm trying to say since I suck at explaining things.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hZS-TQAjzhc&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing WinUSB on Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/489546/installing-winusb-on-ubuntu-14-04). This question is more up-to-date than the question that is claimed to be its duplicate.

Comment: It depends on which version of Ubuntu you are running. possible duplicate of [How do I install WinUSB on 14.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/562535/how-do-i-install-winusb-on-14-10)

Answer (score 0):

Startup Disk Creator will only work with Ubuntu and other Linux distros.

You need to install WinUSB if you want to make bootable USBs containing Windows through Ubuntu.

---

To install WinUSB, open a Terminal and enter the following commands -

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~colingille/+archive/freshlight/+files/winusb_1.0.11+saucy1_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i winusb_1.0.11+saucy1*

sudo apt-get -f install
```

[image]

Comment: When I tried this I got an error. Installation failed !
Exit code: 256